# Android - Relative vs ConstraintLayout - same output with less code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

**Does ConstraintLayout provide any advantage over RelativeLayout for Android - or does ConstraintLayout only add unnecessary complexity?**

This is a sample layout I am building, code snippets are below: [Android Layout Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSl3K.png)

It looks to me that RelativeLayout produces the same result but:

1. Uses fewer lines of code (50 lines vs 72 lines)
2. Does not require guidelines
3. Can be positioned only with **android:layout_width="parent"**, making **app:layout_constraintRight/Left/Top/Bottom="parent""** unnecessary

**Am I missing some advantage to ConstraintLayout over RelativeLayout?**

This is the ConstraintLayout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_patient_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.doclily.doclily.MessagesTab"
    android:background="#fff"  >

    <com.doclily.doclily.style.ViewGrey4
        android:id="@+id/navBarDummyView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/navBarGuideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/navBarGuideline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="48dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"/>

    <com.doclily.doclily.style.TextViewRegularBlack
        android:id="@+id/MessagesTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/action_bar_margin_left"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navBarDummyView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Messages"
        android:textSize="@dimen/base_font_size_24"/>

    <com.doclily.doclily.style.TextViewRegularBlack
        android:id="@+id/placeholderTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Placeholder TextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/navBarDummyView"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/base_font_size_18"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/messagesSwipe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/navBarDummyView">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/threadsTableRecyclerView"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_messaging_tab_row"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the RelativeLayout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_patient_home"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.doclily.doclily.MessagesTab"
    android:background="#fff" >

    <com.doclily.doclily.style.TextViewRegularBlack
        android:id="@+id/MessagesTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/action_bar_margin_left"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Messages"
        android:textSize="@dimen/base_font_size_24"/>

    <com.doclily.doclily.style.ViewGrey4
        android:id="@+id/navBarDummyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MessagesTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

    <com.doclily.doclily.style.TextViewRegularBlack
        android:id="@+id/placeholderTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Placeholder TextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/base_font_size_18"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/messagesSwipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/navBarDummyView">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/threadsTableRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_messaging_tab_row"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For such a simple layout, I see no improvement whatsoever with using a ConstraintLayout over a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Your question is akin to asking "why do we need shovels when we have nuclear weapons? it takes so long to dig a crater with a shovel, when we can get a crater quite easily with a nuke". Some layouts certainly require less XML with a `RelativeLayout` than with a `ConstraintLayout`. Conversely, there are lots of scenarios, outlined in the `ConstraintLayout` documentation, that are impossible with a `RelativeLayout` and less efficient when using other techniques (e.g., percentage-based space allocation).

Comment: By the way, for `percentage-based space allocation` there's PercentRelativeLayout, when you have a simple design. It all depends on how complex your design is. Which is where ConstraintLayouts come in handy.

Comment: @Rotwang thank you. In our case - the layouts are simple. Would you use RelativeLayout / PercentRelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout in such scenarios? Also, do you have a specific example of a more complex layout where ConstraintLayout would definitely be the preferred choice?

Comment: @CommonsWare Or rather - "why do we need nuclear weapons when we have shovels?" I want to build common/simple layouts as efficiently as possible - and I want to understand the best tool for doing so.

Comment: As I already noted, in this specific case, I see no advantage in using a ConstraintLayout. Maybe a more complex interface (if it can't be simplified any further) would benefit from the ConstraintLayout. Always having in mind the goal of keeping your layouts as flat as possible (for performances sake). And because RelativeLayouts are said to be less efficient than other kind of layouts (LinearLayouts and those which inherit from them).

Comment: @Rotwang: `PercentRelativeLayout` is deprecated in the v26 support libraries, in favor of `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: "I want to understand the best tool for doing so" -- that answer will vary by layout. If you want to say that you will only ever use one container class, `ConstraintLayout` will be your best choice. Most developers choose different containers for different situations based upon the characteristics of that particular container. For example, replicating all of `TableLayout`'s functionality *might* be possible with `ConstraintLayout` (though I have never succeeded) and is flat-out impossible with the other standard Android container classes.

Comment: @Commonsware Well, they have a lot of fun in deprecating this and that every now and then... I don't care anymore about deprecations. I use whatever fits my needs better. By the way, did they already deprecate GridLayout? Since I find it handy and I think I won't stop using it.

Comment: "I don't care anymore about deprecations" -- you should when they are in a support library, as there the classes can be removed (as opposed to the framework classes, which generally remain for backwards-compatibility reasons).

Comment: @CommonsWare I stopped caring for deprecations about 4 years ago. Since every day someone woke up and deprecated something. And it was breaking my nerves. So I decided to stop following their caprices. And I live much better.

Answer (score 1):

ConstraintLayout is better to build **responsive** layouts.

I suggest you to read the official guide

> ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.